# SVD decomposition of a matrix M with only real values between 0.0 and 1.0

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, image-processing

I am working to an image compression system based on the SVD decomposition: my image (or a section of it) is the matrix M and contains only valus ranging from 0.0 to 1.0, both inclusive.

I made some test and U and V seems to always hold only values between -1.0 and +1.0 (not sure if inclusive). Is it mathematically true? It is a quite important assumption in order to store efficiently those matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of an orthogonal matrix are unit vectors, which forces its entries to be in $[-1, 1]$.